# Create an account with current date

Tags: jpa

I have a mysql database containing email, pass, and date created.

i already imported entity classes from database.

create jsf pages from entity classes.

account.java

```
@NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)

@NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "login_type")
    private String loginType;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "pwd")
    private String pwd;
    @Basic(optional = false)

@NotNull
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createDate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
```

the system should automatically generate `createDate` depending on what time the account is created, but im confused on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to `Account.java`

```
@PrePersist
public void createdAt() {
    this.createDate = new Date();
}
```

This function will execute automatically before you persist your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code from your xhtml page. Don't take Date as input parameter from end User.

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateAccountLabel_createDate}" for="createDate" />
                    <h:inputText id="createDate" value="#{accountController.selected.createDate}" title="#{bundle.CreateAccountTitle_createDate}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateAccountRequiredMessage_createDate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss" />
                    </h:inputText>
```

Instead, in your managed bean, when you are invoking the method for adding the User, pass Sysdate as parameter to your Insert SQL query.